# LLVM optimizations on non-SSA IR

Tags: optimization, llvm

Although I am aware that LLVM requires the mem2reg pass to be applied for optimizations ,

Is there any way that I can run optimizations on LLVM IR containing loads and stores to stack memory ?

Thanks.

Comment: You just run them normally, but they won't work as well because some passes treat memory loads as opaque values. mem2reg is recommended, not required.

Comment: So at least some like constant prop/copy prop may work on non-SSA IR ?